# For how many values of x, this expression is an integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

$y = \dfrac{24x}{24+x}$

I can't think of a way to split these terms so as to get an estimate of number of integral solutions possible.

Edit: Positive values of x

Comment: Hint : $$24x\equiv 24\cdot (-24)=-576\mod (24+x)$$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha provides [this answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%3D%5Cfrac%7B24x%7D%7B24%2Bx%7D%2C+x%3E0+++over+integers) if that's all you want. Perhaps you can find a pattern in the $10$  solutions shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ and $y$ are integers, with $x$ positive, such that $y=\frac{24x}{24+x}$, then also
$$y=\frac{24x}{24+x}=\frac{24(24+x)-24^2}{24+x}=24-\frac{24^2}{24+x}.$$
So this boils down to counting the divisors of $24^2$ that are greater than $24$.

Answer (score 2):

We must have $24+x\mid 24x\Rightarrow24+x\mid24x+24^2-24^2=24(24+x)-24^2$ which means that $24+x\mid 24^2$. But, $24^2$ has many divisors. Since $24^2=2^6\cdot 3^2$ it has $(6+1)(2+1)=21$ divisors (if you let negative divisors then it has 42!)
So, if $x$ is an integer you have to solve $42$ equations.
For example $24+x=1, 24+x=-1, 24+x=2$ etc. There $42$ values of $x$.

Comment: The OP has now edited to say $x$ is positive, so that very much reduces the number of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram Alpha provides [this answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%3D%5Cfrac%7B24x%7D%7B24%2Bx%7D%2C+x%3E0+++over+integers) if that's all you want. Perhaps you can find a pattern in the $10$  solutions shown.

If you want more, consider
$\quad x = \dfrac{24 y}{24-y} \quad\text{where}\quad x>0\implies  0<y<24\quad$ which limits the max number of solutions to be tested to $23.$